# Modify the legend placement of a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am using a package program that return me a `matplotlib.figure` object together with a legend. I want to change the bounding box and placement of the legend. After checking https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/figure_api.html I tried to retrieve the legend as follows:

```
ax = f.axes[0]
lgd_f = f.legend()
lgd = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
print(lgd_f)
print(lgd)
ax.get_legend().set_bbox_to_anchor((1, 1.05))
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1.05), loc=8)
```

However, this did not work as expected as calling the `get_legend_handles_labels` method on the axes returns two empty lists. Unfortunately it is not possible to modify the internals of the package program. Assuming this is possible could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you could give the name of the package and the function that returns `matplotlib.figure`, it will help.

Comment: What do you mean by *did not work as expected*? What were you expecting and what did you get? Was there an error? FYI, you should try - `handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` to get the handles and labels...

Comment: @Redox this returns two empty lists. I call the function before the plt.show() call that results in the plot being displayed.

Comment: @Z-Y.L the software is IPKISS a proprietary photonic integrated circuit design software by Luceda Photonics.

Answer (score 3):

The OP stated in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302219/matplotlib-figure-modify-the-legend-placement/76304744#comment134555290_76302219) that they had a problem with "empty lists". Fortunately I experienced no such problem.

The solution follows from the code the OP posted, the only issue being changing the location of the Legend from default (0) to the requested one — solved using a private method of the Legend object.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():
    f, a = plt.subplots()
    a.plot((0,1),(0,1), label='SW-NE')
    a.plot((0,1),(1,0), label='NW-SE')
    plt.legend()
    return f

f = plot()
a = f.axes[0]
l = a.get_legend()
l.set_bbox_to_anchor((1, 1.05))
l._set_loc(8) # "private" method
f.set_layout_engine('constrained')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I managed to solve the issue. The problem was that the blackbox function was internally calling the `plt.show()` from matplotlib and this was causing the plot not to be updated. 

There was a keyword argument that needs to be set to `False` (enter_mainloop=False) in the function returning the figure for the commands to work and the `plt.show()` to do the final plotting.

As far as I understand it is not possible to update matplotlib plots after the call `plt.show()`.